# CentOS VLAN tagging is not working

Tags: linux, networking, centos, centos7, vlan

I am trying to enable two VLANS in CentOS 7 and following the article of Redhat.

1.Configure the parent interface in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1, where X is a unique number corresponding to a specific interface, as follows:

```
DEVICE=em1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
```

2.Configure the VLAN interface configuration in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ directory. The configuration file name should be the parent interface plus a . character plus the VLAN ID number. For example, if the VLAN ID is 192, and the parent interface is em1, then the configuration file name should be ifcfg-em1.192

```
DEVICE=em1.192
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.1
PREFIX=24
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
VLAN=yes
```

If there is a need to configure a second VLAN, with for example, VLAN ID 193, on the same interface, em1, add a new file with the name em1.193 with the VLAN configuration details.

```
DEVICE=em1.193
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.2.1
PREFIX=24
NETWORK=192.168.2.0
VLAN=yes
```

3.Restart the networking service in order for the changes to take effect. As root issue the following command

```
systemctl restart network
```

When i do this the network does not work. But if i remove the vlan tagging and just keeping the initial configuration it works again.

Update Switch config:

```
show running-config interface ethernet 1/1/21
interface ethernet 1/1/21
 dual-mode  192
 speed-duplex 1000-full-auto-master-slave
 no spanning-tree
 broadcast limit 8192
 multicast limit
!

PORT-VLAN 192, Name 192.168.1.0/24, Priority level0, Spanning tree Off
DualMode Ports: (U1/M1) 21

PORT-VLAN 193, Name 192.168.2.1/24, Priority level0, Spanning tree Off
 Untagged Ports: None
   Tagged Ports: (U1/M1)  21

Port       Link    State   Dupl Speed Trunk Tag Pvid Pri MAC           Name 
1/1/21     Up      Forward Full 1G    None  Yes 192 0   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```

The issue is Once 1 VLAN is working the other stops. If i restore it back to normal the 192 works and the 193 stops working.

```
#show vlan brief ethernet 1/1/21

Port 1/1/21 is a member of 2 VLANs
VLANs 192 193
```

Comment: Check the configuration of the switch port.

Comment: Michael, the switch configuration is good from what i can see. But i can share this with you if it helps

Comment: Yes, you need to share it. You also need to share anything else that may be relevant, whether you are asked for it or not.

Comment: @MichaelHampton added the switch configuration.

Comment: Did you check if 8021q module is loaded? `lsmod |grep 8021q`. If not load it: `sudo modprobe --first-time 8021q`

Comment: @tonioc the module is loaded. Where do I have to configure the two gateways?

Comment: You can add routes using nmcli or merely in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-em1.192 and 193, using syntax described in networking guide https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-editing_network_configuration_files#sec-Static-Routes_and_the_Default_Gateway

Comment: @tonioc why is this not described in the vlan tagging page of RH :( Beside the route.em1.192 i had to create an rule.em1.192. Why ?

Comment: Because this is  not specific to VLAN interfaces,  but the general way to handle routing...

Comment: @tonioc thanks for your help so far. I was able to fix the issue after adding the route and rule file for the network (vlan) and adding alias for every ip.